# How to disable a form element in a Zend Form?

Tags: html, css, zend-framework, zend-form

I want to display a Zend Form with one of the elements shown as disabled. I'm setting the value so the user can see it, but I want to disable it so the user can't edit it. This may also involve some sort of css/javascript to ensure that it looks like, and is not editable by the user. This is my element:

```
    $this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
        'label'      => 'Username:',
        'required'   => true,
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array(
            array('StringLength', false, array(2, 50))
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
$this->username->setAttrib('disabled', 'disabled');
```

I think you can as well:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
    'label'      => 'Username:',
    'required'   => true,
    'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
    'validators' => array(
        array('StringLength', false, array(2, 50))
    ),
    'attribs'    => array('disabled' => 'disabled')
));
```

Comment: Note that you should use 'disable' instead of 'disabled' on a CheckBox, because of this bug : http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9149

Comment: Same here, this worked and was just what I needed. Quick and effective.

Answer (score 6):

This works fine...
Just to complete the help:
If you are in a controller you can do:

```
$form->selRole->setAttribs(array('disable' => 'disable'));
```

selRole is the name of a select field

Comment: Does disable really work instead of disabled or is this an error.

Answer (score 1):

In latest zf2.2.1 you can do this in your controller;

```
$form->get('username')->setAttributes(array(
    'disabled' => 'disabled',  
));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$form->getElement("username")->setAttribs(array('disabled' => 'disabled', ));
```

or

```
$form->getElement("username")->setAttrib('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

$var->setAttribs(array('disabled' => 'disabled'));

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code into your Application

```
$formelement->setAttrib('readonly', 'true');
$formelement->setAttrib('style', 'pointer-events: none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this was working for me, when using a `file element` when setting after form was submitted:

```
$element->setValueDisabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// disable checkbox using JS add-on
$checkbox->setAttribute('onclick', 'return false');
```

Benefit:  retains the original color of the box but does not let the user change the value of the box.

Using `disabled` method of other answers changes the color of checkbox to "grayed out".  Method described here, does not.

Answer (score 0):

@Dennis:

Disabling Javascript is enough to enable the form again, so you can't truly rely on Javascript. Using native HTML disables it better, but is also simply worked around, by removing the disabled attribute.

Best option is showing the values you want instead of the form itself and disable the form and/or it's elements.

Wish I could add the comment directly to your post, but I'm some rep short.